# Buffer size in Erlang / Golang port example

Tags: go, erlang

I have a crude Erlang-to-Golang port example, passing data from Erlang to Golang and echoing the response.

Problem is the amount of data I can transfer seems to be limited to 2^8 bytes (see below). I thought the problem was probably on the Golang side (not creating a big enough buffer) but replacing bufio.NewReader with bufio.NewReaderSize didn't work. So am now thinking the problem is maybe on the Erlang side.

What do I need to do to increase the buffer size / be able to echo a message larger than 2^8 bytes ?

TIA

```
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/erlang_golang_port$ erl -pa ebin
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.4.1  (abort with ^G)
1> port:start("./echo").
<0.35.0>
2> port:ping(65000).
65000
3> port:ping(66000).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  port:call_port/1 (port.erl, line 20)
4> port:start("./echo").
<0.40.0>
5> port:ping(66000).    
65536
```

---

**Go**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

const Delimiter = '\n'

func main() {
    // reader := bufio:NewReader(os.Stdin)
    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1677216) // 2**24;
    bytes, _ := reader.ReadBytes(Delimiter)
    os.Stdout.Write(bytes[:len(bytes)-1])
}
```

---

**Erlang**

```
-module(port).

-export([start/1, stop/0, init/1]).

-export([ping/1]).

-define(DELIMITER, [10]).

start(ExtPrg) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, init, [ExtPrg]).

stop() ->
    myname ! stop.

ping(N) ->
    Msg=[round(65+26*random:uniform()) || _ <- lists:seq(1, N)],
    call_port(Msg).

call_port(Msg) ->
    myname ! {call, self(), Msg},
    receive
    {myname, Result} ->
        length(Result)
    end.

init(ExtPrg) ->
    register(myname, self()),
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Port = open_port({spawn, ExtPrg}, []),
    loop(Port).

loop(Port) ->
    receive
    {call, Caller, Msg} ->
        Port ! {self(), {command, Msg++?DELIMITER}},
        receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            Caller ! {myname, Data}
        end,
        loop(Port);
    stop ->
        Port ! {self(), close},
        receive
        {Port, closed} ->
            exit(normal)
        end;
    {'EXIT', Port, _Reason} ->
        exit(port_terminated)
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `start_link` instead, you'll see that the port crashes after the first command:

```erlang
1> port:start('go run port.go').
<0.118.0>
2> port:ping(65000).
65000
** exception error: port_terminated
```

If you change the Go code to run in a loop, this crash can be avoided:

```
func main() {
    for {
        // reader := bufio:NewReader(os.Stdin)
        reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1677216) // 2**24;
        bytes, _ := reader.ReadBytes(Delimiter)
        os.Stdout.Write(bytes[:len(bytes)-1])
    }
}
```

Now we can see another interesting result:

```erlang
33> c(port).
{ok,port}
40> port:ping(66000).
65536
41> port:ping(66000).
464
42> port:ping(66000).
65536
43> port:ping(66000).
464
```

Now we can see that no data is actually lost, it's just buffered in the port. Since you have not specified a framing protocol (using `{packet, N}` or `{line, N}` you are responsible yourself for collecting the data. It also seems that the internal buffer size of an Erlang port is 64K (although I found no documentation of this and no way to change it).

If you change your receive to get all data before returning, you'll every byte each time:

```erlang
loop(Port) ->
    receive
    {call, Caller, Msg} ->
        Port ! {self(), {command, Msg++?DELIMITER}},
        Caller ! {myname, receive_all(Port, 10)},
        loop(Port);
    stop ->
        Port ! {self(), close},
        receive
        {Port, closed} ->
            exit(normal)
        end;
    {'EXIT', Port, _Reason} ->
        exit(port_terminated)
    end.

receive_all(Port, Timeout) -> receive_all(Port, Timeout, []).

receive_all(Port, Timeout, Data) ->
    receive
    {Port, {data, New}} ->
        receive_all(Port, Timeout, [New|Data])
    after Timeout ->
        lists:flatten(lists:reverse(Data))
    end.
```

Running this, we get:

```erlang
1> c(port).
{ok,port}
2>
3> port:start('go run port.go').
<0.311.0>
4> port:ping(66000).
66000
5> port:ping(66000).
66000
6> port:ping(66000).
66000
```

Comment: Your `receice_all/3` is O(N^2) due `Data ++ New`. It is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

1. 2^8 is 256, not 65536 which is 2^16 (or 2 bytes).
2. For excluding golang program you can simply replace your `echo` with GNU `cat`
3. Default message max size for port communication is 64k, so when your port receives messages, the first one is leading 64k of the string. You can read port *again*  to gain remaining data but you just drop them in your code.
4. If you really want to communicate on line-based protocol you should configure your port [accordingly](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2):

> `{line, L}`
>
> Messages are delivered on a per line basis. Each line
>   (delimited by the OS-dependent newline sequence) is delivered in one
>   single message. The message data format is {Flag, Line}, where Flag is
>   either eol or noeol and Line is the actual data delivered (without the
>   newline sequence).
>
> `L` specifies the maximum line length in bytes. Lines longer than this
>   will be delivered in more than one message, with the Flag set to noeol
>   for all but the last message. If end of file is encountered anywhere
>   else than immediately following a newline sequence, the last line will
>   also be delivered with the Flag set to noeol. In all other cases,
>   lines are delivered with Flag set to eol.
>
> The `{packet, N}` and `{line, L}` settings are mutually exclusive.

So your code would be

```
Port = open_port({spawn, ExtPrg}, [{line, ?PACKET_SIZE]),
%%...
{call, Caller, Msg} ->
    Port ! {self(), {command, Msg++?DELIMITER}},
    D = read_data(Port, []),
    Caller ! {myname, D},
    loop(Port);
%%...
read_data(Port, Prefix) ->
receive
    {Port, {data, {noeol, Data}}} ->
        read_data(Port, Prefix ++ Data);
    {Port, {data, {eol, Data}}} ->
        Prefix ++ Data
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the similar problem.
Here the complete code of pipe module.

It allows sent text data to port and read all replies.

```
-module(apr_pipe).

-export([open_pipe/2,send/2,close/1]).

-export([loop/1,status/1,init/1]).

-include_lib("kernel/include/logger.hrl").

-define(MAX_LINE_LEN,4096).

open_pipe(Path,Cmd) ->
   State = #{path => Path, cmd => Cmd},
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE,init,[State]),
    Pid.

init(State) ->
    #{path := Path,cmd := Cmd} = State,
    FullFn = filename:join(Path,Cmd),
    Settings = [{line,?MAX_LINE_LEN},use_stdio,stderr_to_stdout,hide,binary,exit_status],
    Port = erlang:open_port({spawn_executable,FullFn},Settings),
    State2 = State#{port => Port, data => #{}},
    loop(State2).


send(Pid,Data)  -> Pid!{self(),send,Data}.
close(Pid)      -> Pid!{self(),send,close}.
status(Pid)     -> Pid!{self(),status}.

get_eol() -> <<"\n">>.

loop(State) ->
    receive
        {_Pid,send,close} -> 
                    ?LOG(notice,"got cmd: Close",[]),
                    Port = maps:get(port,State),
                    port_close(Port),
                    exit(normal);
        {Pid,send,Data} ->
                    ?LOG(notice,"Send Data ...",[]),
                    Port = maps:get(port,State),
                    port_command(Port,Data),
                    port_command(Port,get_eol()),
                    State2 = State#{status => data_sent, client => Pid},
                    loop(State2);
         {Pid,status} -> 
                    Port = maps:get(port,State),
                    ?LOG(notice,"Status: Port: ~p State: ~p",[Port,State]),
                    Pid!{status,Port,State},
                    loop(State);
        % port messages.
        {Port, {data,{noeol,Data}}} ->
                ?LOG(notice,"Port: ~p Data: ~p",[Port,Data]),
                CurData = maps:get(cur_data,State,[]),
                State2 = State#{cur_data => [Data | CurData]},
                loop(State2);

        {Port, {data, {eol,Data}}} ->
                ?LOG(notice,"Port: ~p Data: ~p",[Port,Data]),
                CurData = [Data | maps:get(cur_data,State,[])],
                CurData2 = lists:reverse(CurData),
                Reply    = list_to_binary(CurData2),
                Client = maps:get(client,State,undefined),
                State2 = State#{cur_data => [], client => undefined},
                case Client of
                    undefined -> ?LOG(error,"can not sent reply. Client: ~p Reply: ~p", [Client,Reply]),
                                 loop(State2);
                    _ -> Client!{reply,Reply},
                         loop(State2)
                 end;
        {_Port, closed} ->
                ?LOG(warning, "Port: ~p closed",[]),
                exit(normal);
        {'EXIT',  Port, Reason} ->
                 ?LOG(notice,"Port: ~p exit. Reason: ~p",[Port,Reason]),
                 exit(Reason);
        _Other -> ?LOG(error,"unexpected message: ~p",[_Other]),
                  exit({error,{unexpected_message,_Other}})
    end.
```